# Issues observed in PSPDFKit after upgrading to latest version 5.1.5

Tags: ios, pspdfkit

I am using PSPDFKit in one of my applications and recently I have updated its version using cocoa-pods

I have observed some number of errors after upgrading PSPDF kit to the latest version.

The xCode version I am using is 6.4.

Some of errors are: While importing PSPDFKit its showing an error as  ["**Could not build module PSPDFKi**t"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7oSc.png)

[and the other errors shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxYBk.png).
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the head of PSPDFKit.

Please check out our [Version Support Guide](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/announcements/version-support/), which explains that for PSPDFKit 5.x, you need Xcode 7.x (the latest version, so 7.2 currently).

The biggest reason here is that we've invested a lot of time to make our headers better interoperable with Swift, using the new Generics and Nullability additions that came with Xcode 7. This is also very useful if you still use Objective-C.

Heads up:
We don't monitor StackOverflow for support but have our own platform to ask questions, please use https://pspdfkit.com/support/request in the future. Thanks!